# Decoding merkle root passed as child trie parameter

Tags: trie

We implemented decentralised reward campaigns using child tries. Currently we are using the **AccountId** together with  **TrieIndex** and **Balance** or **NftId** as parameters (depending on the type of campaign rewards). However, we want to implement amore scalable solution which uses a merkle root instead of AccountId. This will allow adding multiple entries using a single extrinsic call. We managed to implement this solution for setting rewards but we need to decode the root in order to check if an account submitted a valid reward claim call. What would be the best way to approach this?

P.S. You can find the current version of the implementation [here](https://github.com/chexware/Bit-Country-Blockchain/tree/feature/campaigns-scalability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to solve this issue by calculating the **mekrle proof** when claiming the reward, using claiming information (**AccountId** and **Balance /  list of NftIds**) together with passing a **sorted list of all relevant leaf and inner nodes hashes** as extrinsic parameters.